# Linux cmd to copy file to an existing file without overwriting it

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, file-moving

Now I am having two files. File A and file B. Both files contain of information inside.
I am having issues on how to copy the information in file A to file B without removing or overwriting the information in file B by using Linux command prompt.

File A:

```
1
2
3
```

File B:

```
A
B
```

What i want to achieve by using Linux prompt:
File B:

```
A
B
1
2
3
```

Please advice me on how should I do it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about concatenating the files?

Like

```
$ cat A >> B
```

The `cat` command will display the contents of file `A`, but the redirection operator (`>>`) will cause the output to be appended to the end of file `B`.

Or if you don't want to change the contents of either file, you can use the `cat` command to create a third file (`cat` actually stands for conCATenate):

```
$ cat A B > C
```

The above command will display the contents of file `A` followed by the contents of file `B`, with the output redirected (with `>`) to create a new file `C` which will contain the contents of file `A` and `B`.